# Hadoop 2.7.2 - Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-15.10, hadoop-2.7.2

I am newbie and I am trying to find out a solution to this problem.
I have followed this turorial in order to setup Hadoop 2.7.2 on Ubuntu 15.10

http://idroot.net/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-hadoop-on-ubuntu-14-04/

When I launch "hdfs namenode format" I continue to receive this error
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

this is the bashrc content

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

export HADOOP_INSTALL=/usr/local/hadoop

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin

export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL

export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native

export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

Can anyone help me to solve this (stupid I think) question?

Many thanks
Kama

Comment: I have updated my answer, however if that doesn't work you can use my installation script for Hadoop [here](https://github.com/user501254/BD_STTP_2016/blob/master/InstallHadoop.sh). Remember to go through it before running.

Comment: See related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888460/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-hadoop-hdfs-server-namenode/

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the directories *namenode* and *datanode* already exist in the location specified within the `hdfs-site.xml` file. You can use the command `mkdir` to create those.

Then try to format the namenode using

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

or

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs namenode -format
```

Please note the hyphen.

---

My bashrc configuration for hadoop:

```
#HADOOP VARIABLES START
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
#HADOOP VARIABLES END
```

Comment: Hi! I have checked directories but I still receive this error. I am using an oracle JRE instead a specific (openjdk) JDK. Could this be responsible? My opinion is that the issue is related to some the class not found so to hdfs command in unable to find the desired class

Comment: Try changing all occurrences of "HADOOP_INSTALL" to "HADOOP_HOME" or "HADOOP_PREFIX" in your bashrc file.

Comment: IMO, JRE should work just fine as long as you aren't making any applications of your own.

Comment: @RobertoG. 2.7.2, which is the most current version.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using the Ashes Script. Main difference is the usage of open jdk instead of oracle jre.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too. For me, it's just because some files in /share/hadoop/yarn/ folder is missing, which was caused by an **incomplete download of hadoop.tar.gz** that can still be abstracted by command line. May help you, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One cause behind this problem might be a user-defined `HDFS_DIR` environment variable. This is picked up by scripts such as the following lines in `libexec/hadoop-functions.sh`:

```
HDFS_DIR=${HDFS_DIR:-"share/hadoop/hdfs"}
...
if [[ -z "${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}" ]] &&
   [[ -d "${HADOOP_HOME}/${HDFS_DIR}" ]]; then
  export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME="${HADOOP_HOME}"
fi
```

The solution is to avoid defining an environment variable `HDFS_DIR`.

In my case, using `sudo` helped but for the wrong reasons: there was no problem with the permissions but with the environment variables.