# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode Tried all solution still error persists

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am following tutorial to install hadoop. It is explained with hadoop 1.x but I am using hadoop-2.6.0

I have successfully completed all the step just before executing following cmd.

> bin/hadoop namenode -format

I am getting the following error when I execute the above command.

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

My hadoop-env.sh file

```
 The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74"

# The jsvc implementation to use. Jsvc is required to run secure datanodes
# that bind to privileged ports to provide authentication of data transfer
# protocol.  Jsvc is not required if SASL is configured for authentication of
# data transfer protocol using non-privileged ports.
#export JSVC_HOME=${JSVC_HOME}

export HADOOP_PREFIX="/home/582092/hadoop-2.6.0"

export HADOOP_HOME="/home/582092/hadoop-2.6.0"
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
#export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-"/etc/hadoop"}
```

**core-site.xml**

[core-site.xml Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUyhK.jpg)

**hdfs-site.xml**

> dfs.data.dir 
>   /home/582092/hadoop-dir/datadir   
>     dfs.name.dir 
>   /home/582092/hadoop-dir/namedir

---

Kindly help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: It seems the jar `hadoop-hdfs-*.jar` can't be able to find when running namenode format

Comment: type `hadoop classpath` in command line and check `hadoop-hdfs-*.jar` is present in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

One cause behind this problem might be a user-defined `HDFS_DIR` environment variable. This is picked up by scripts such as the following lines in `libexec/hadoop-functions.sh`:

```
HDFS_DIR=${HDFS_DIR:-"share/hadoop/hdfs"}
...
if [[ -z "${HADOOP_HDFS_HOME}" ]] &&
   [[ -d "${HADOOP_HOME}/${HDFS_DIR}" ]]; then
  export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME="${HADOOP_HOME}"
fi
```

The solution is to avoid defining an environment variable `HDFS_DIR`.

The recommendations in the comments of question are correct – use the `hadoop classpath` command to identify whether `hadoop-hdfs-*.jar` files are present in the classpath or not. They were missing in my case.